# Criar chave primaria em uma tabela que já existe no sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

Fiz a importação de um arquivo `txt` com seis milhões de linhas para uma tabela do SqlServer.

Agora eu quero criar uma chave primaria nela, o problema é que nenhum coluna garante integridade, por isso quero criar uma outra coluna com auto incrementação.

Como eu faria isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para gerar a coluna basta fazer o seguinte:

Primeiro criar uma coluna com a auto incrementação:

```
alter table TABELA
add id [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Depois transformar essa coluna em uma chave primaria.

```
ALTER TABLE TABELA
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_NOME PRIMARY KEY (id)
```